# Use of 'which' versus 'that'

Tags: syntactic-analysis, indefinite-pronouns

The examples are as follows.

- The idea that has drawn a significant interest is very hard to design.
- The idea, which has drawn a significant interest, is very hard to design.
- The idea that has drawn a significant interest, is very hard to design.

Need help on defining and nondefining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are OK but they mean different things. The third one is the same as the first one with an unnecessary comma.

In the first sentence, "that has drawn a significant interest" serves to define which idea is being discussed (i.e., the sentence is referring to the idea that has drawn a significant interest). This is a [defining relative clause](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/defining-relative-clauses/).

In the second sentence, "which has drawn a significant interest" set off by commas is giving additional information about the idea being discussed (i.e., we already know which idea is being referred to). This is a [non-defining relative clause](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/non-defining-relative-clauses/).

Comment: Now, it is clear to me. I get one more doubt, is the 'comma' really unnecessary or does it have any impact on this sentence?

Comment: The comma in the third sentence is incorrect. It's separating the subject from the verb, which is not correct usage. Consider a simpler example: "Bill, likes ice cream." It's probably obvious that there shouldn't be a comma there. In the second sentence, the part between the commas is a parenthetical phrase, which must be separated from the rest of the sentence by commas (or other punctuation such as parentheses or dashes).